# Special characters with json in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get the data that is in the database and show them in json. But the words that have an accent are coming up like this: \ u00f3.

My code is like this:
cidadeDao.php

```
<?php

class CidadeDAO {
    private $conexao;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conexao = new Conexao();
    }

    public function consultarTodos() {

       // mysql_set_charset('utf8');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cidade";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql);

        return $resultado;
    }

}

?>
```

cidade.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);

include '../Classes/Conexao.php';
include '../Classes/DAO/cidadeDao.php';

$cidadeDao = new cidadeDao();

$consulta = $cidadeDao->consultarTodos();

    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($consulta); $i++){
        $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

        $respostas [] = array (
            'id' => $linha['id'],
            'id_uf' => $linha['id_uf'],
            'cidade' => utf8_encode($linha['cidade'])
        );
    }

echo json_encode($respostas);
?>
```

When I check the json that is generated it looks like this:

```
[{"id":"1","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Sorocaba"},
{"id":"2","id_uf":"5","cidade":"Niter\u00f3i"},
{"id":"3","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Tatui"},
{"id":"4","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Itu"}]
```

Can anybody help me?

How can I handle words with accents and special characters in php?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? When [json_decoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) they should be turned into whatever they where before. And frontend JS should display them just right.

Comment: The php function `utf8_encode` you're using does that, but what are you expecting? That's how it should look like.

Comment: In my json it was supposed to be appearing like this: [{"id":"1","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Sorocaba"},
{"id":"2","id_uf":"5","cidade":"Niterói"},
{"id":"3","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Tatui"},
{"id":"4","id_uf":"1","cidade":"Itu"}] @DainisAbols

Comment: No, it is not supposed to appear like that, that is not the [json way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548400/special-characters-with-json-in-php?noredirect=1#comment78056685_45548400).

Comment: But since it has a special character in the word that comes from the database, I am not able to convert the whole word. @DainisAbols

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to convert the whole word? `Niter\u00f3i` seems fully and correctly converted `Niterói`. Have you tried printing out the json in the frontend or decoding to see if its the same? Or what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I tried to follow the php documentation doing this: $respostas = array_map('htmlentities', $respostas);

$json = html_entity_decode(json_encode($respostas));

echo ($json);

Comment: But it does not work, json came this way: [null, null, null, null] @DainisAbols

Comment: Check my answer, see if it solves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual page on JSON Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) (you really should start there)

`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

so

```
json_encode('Niterói', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**Edit:** Also please see comments for reasons this approach can be problematic (it actually violates the RFC for JSON).

Comment: This is dangerous, since there is a high risk you will loose encoding, when sending data from backend to frontend. Especially between different servers like API and the Website. There is a good reason why it's encoded the way it is.

Comment: This answers the OP question. I'd suggest your comment warning is enough, but also that they consult https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 if concerned. Things working as they request and being compatible I'd suggest is something they or someone they pay should work out for their specific case. Thanks for the tip though (I'd sooner encode the string I was searching for before searching, but I don't store JSON anywhere I search).

Comment: I just did as you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much I did so:echo json_encode($respostas, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); @MrMesees

Answer (score 1):

- You should use the `mb_internal_encoding()` function at the top of every file and `the mb_http_output()` function right after it .
- Your database and tables that need to be set to the `utf8mb4` character set and collation.
- To save to database, use htmlentities and by precising UTF-8 like this `htmlentities( $yourdata, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' );`

and you must add this to access the database for mysqli :

```
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');
```

**Read here**-- Working with UTF-8, FROM PHP the right way. http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8

- It explains how to use UTF-8 the right way at the PHP level, database level and the browser level.

Answer (score 0):

That's how JSON appears, however once you decode it using whatever you are using to decode it will appear fine. So `Niter\u00f3i` will appear like this in JSON but once you [JSON Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it, it will appear as a normal string `Niterói`